# Selenium proxy unable to connect with Chrome

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've been attempting to connect to an HTTPS proxy for hours and can't seem to figure out why it's not working. I'm using Python 3.9.0 with Selenium 3.141.0 and Chrome 92.0.4515.159. I'm grabbing free HTTPS- and Google-accessible proxies from [here](https://free-proxy-list.net), and using the following preferences:

```py
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
useragent = UserAgent.random

options.add_argument(f"--user-agent={useragent}")
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_argument(f"--proxy-server={proxystring}")

capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
capabilities["AcceptSslCerts"] = True
capabilities["marionette"] = True

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, desired_capabilities=capabilities)
```

where `proxystring` is a `<host>:<port>` string. Whenever I attempt to use the proxy, I get the following Chrome error: [image: ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED error.]

Whenever I don't use the proxy, the page loads fine – I'm just confused as to why my attempt to use proxies isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, free proxies from https://free-proxy-list.net/ and other similar websites have very low success rate and work very rarely.

I'd suggest you to use premium proxies or other methods to avoid detection such as User-Agent rotation, using more waits etc.